# Asp.net core Kubernetes job set to failed status on exception

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes job running a BackgroundService in Asp.net Core.

After doing some processing the BackgroundService initiates a shutdown by calling StopApplication.

Is there a way to shutdown the application and set the Kubernetes job to failed status when there is an exception in a BackgroundService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is there a way to shutdown the application and set the Kubernetes job
>   to failed status ... ?"

Yes, by anticipating that your application will exit with non-zero exit code when encountering an exception. That's the way how Kubernetes Job's final [status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#handling-pod-and-container-failures) is determined.

In other words, if container's process finishes with non-zero code, it causes Pod to terminate and eventually the Job status becomes `'Failed'`.

In case of stopping ASP.NET Core Application programmatically, with `'StopApplication()'` method, it exits with `'0'` exit code (example usage [here](https://edi.wang/post/2019/3/7/restart-an-aspnet-core-application-programmatically)).

**Possible solution:**

You program needs to handle an exception, even like graceful shutdown = `StopApplication()`, by explicitly setting an exit code to non-zero one beforehand (`[1,250]`).

Pseudo code:

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Worker process caught exception");

            Environment.ExitCode = 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
        }
```

based on example [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/2363#issuecomment-532719733).

Comment: Found out [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) there is no job status but pod status. Set backofflimit to 0 to not create a new pod after failure of first pod.